# Laravel 5.2 route with optional parameters not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i just can't seem to find the problem, hope someone can help me.

Im trying to reach my controller, and then use my parameter, but it alwasy says its missing the parameter.

Route file:

```
Route::get('admin/site-settings/global-data/{part?}/', ['as' => 'admin/global-data-edit', 'uses' => 'admin\GlobalDatasController@getGlobalData']);
```

Function:

```
    public function getGlobalData(Request $request, $part){

    $globalData = GlobalData::find(1);

    switch ($part){

        case "content":

            if($request->ajax()){
                return view('admin.site-settings.global-data._ajax_load_content', compact('globalData'));
            }

            return view('admin.site-settings.global-data.edit')->with('globalData', $globalData);

            break;

        case "logo":

            if($request->ajax()){
                return view('admin.site-settings.global-data._ajax_load_logo', compact('globalData'));
            }

            return view('admin.site-settings.global-data.edit')->with('globalData', $globalData);

            break;
    }


}
```

AND my View:

```
        function load_data() {
        $('#load-data').hide().html('<div class="loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>').fadeIn();
        var url = '{{route('admin/global-data-edit')}}';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
                $data = $(data);
                $('#load-data').hide().html($data).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you so muych for your time in advance!

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
public function getGlobalData(Request $request, $part){
```

to:

```
public function getGlobalData(Request $request, $part = null){
```

Comment: Thank you,  but its empty, so this just forces null.

Comment: If you want the route parameter to be optional you'll need to provide a default value to the $part parameter in your controller method.  If you don't want it to be optional you'll have to remove the question mark in your route definition and always pass it.

Comment: Okay im gonna try that, Thank you very much.